# parse in android getInBackground function is not running

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

Can anyone help me out that why is the function `getInBackground` is not running i want to fetch the data from parse in android.
This is my class which calls the function of `fetchData(String themeId)` in `parseManipulate` class

```
public class selectTheme extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button gBtn;
Button rBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.themeselection);

    String themeid = "ECGo4oSKgU";
    ParseManipulate pm = new ParseManipulate();

    pm.fetchData(themeid);


/*      gBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.greentheme);
    rBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redtheme);

    gBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    rBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
*/  
}
```

And this is my fetchData() function in ParseManipulate class.compiler does not run the function getInBackground() function and jumps at the end of function closing bracket

```
public class ParseManipulate {

    public void fetchData(String ThemeId)
    {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("testThemes");

    pq.getInBackground(ThemeId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>(){

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e == null)
            {
            //  value = object.getString("ThemeName");
                Log.d("ParseObject", ""+object.getString("ThemeName"));
            }
            else
            {
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error in data fetching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
    }
}
```

Comment: From the sounds of it you are using a debugger, and stepping over the lines of code. In that case the code will skip past the contents of your `getInBackground()` call, since that code will be called when the async operation finishes. This could be a second or more after the call to `getInBackground()` depending on query complexity and internet issues.

Comment: @TimothyWalters thanx bro i hav done this u r right :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of      

 Log.d("ParseObject", ""+object.getString("ThemeName"));
```

Use it like this

```
Log.d("ParseObject", ""+object.fetchIfNeeded().getString("ThemeName"));
```